# WDAC Status checked via C++ and Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, service, windows-defender, applocker

So, I have been working on a project to make a Windows Service. While doing so, I set my target for the project to check on diffrent parts of the PC and its status. Windows Firewall, Antivirus and its health. Monitor use of folders and what not.

All of it have worked fairly well, Windows API got a lot of functions to get information on most things. But I can not find ANYTHING for checking status of WDAC and/or AppLocker.

Outside of scripts, there is no real way that I can find that solve this. I COULD print system information using msinfo32 and then parse the file for the information. But it feels like it is so, so costly as an operation. Many of the other checks I do are small and cheap, thus can be done over and over without issues. But read/write takes time and effort, and is not a thing you want to spam a lot.

Looking around, I can not find a pure C++ solution outside of this. So want to ask here, for help on how it can be solved OR if I missed something.